# Using a Dedicated Class & Constructor to initialize Stored Procedure for SQL Transaction

Tags: c#, optimization, asp.net, sql-server

I will try to be as concise as I can:

**The goal:** trying to universalize a specific section of a project, that is dealing with the SQL database transactions.

To assist you with your answer, I've pasted the following (just for reference):

- a usage code: `GetTestOfTablTime()` returns a `DataTable`
- class: `SQLDBInteraction` is another class - responsible for the final(SQL transaction) stage

In this code below, I am constructing what I call: "Stored Procedure's Meta Data".  That class is the one that holds all of the SQL Db SPs.

`HTSPs` (HT is the  company's aliases) is holding each `SP` required) parameters.  `HTSPs` class contains another sub Class.  For all `SP`s Names, it only has `const string`s for each `SP` name.

```C#
public sealed class HTSPs
{

//so for example this is one of the members of this class - a stored procedure
//its mission: get evnents with specified id OF specified userId in spec' month, year..

    public sealed class GetTimesWithCustomerNames
    {
        //if I DO need Constructor for its parameters how do I properly format the constructor?
        public GetTimesWithCustomerNames()
        {
            Userid.ParameterName = ParNameUserid;
            Month.ParameterName = ParNameMonth;
            Year.ParameterName = ParNameYear;
            EventId.ParameterName = ParNameReasonid;

        }

        const string ParNameUserId = "@userId",
                     ParNameMonth = "@month",
                     ParNameYear = "@year",
                     ParNameEventId = "@eventId";

        public static SqlParameter Userid = new SqlParameter();
        public static SqlParameter Month = new SqlParameter();
        public static SqlParameter Year = new SqlParameter();
        public static SqlParameter EventId = new SqlParameter();            
    }
}
```

The issue is:  how do I initialize the contractor?  What is the proper way to have your simple customized `StoredProcedure` "MetaData"?  I've currently completed the implementation of the method below (apart from that issue).

**USAGE**

This is a method that returns `DataTable` while using the `HTSPs` class / constructor.

```C#
using SPTime = HT_DBSchema.HTSPs.GetTimesWithCustomerNames;

private DataTable GetTestOfTablTime()
{
    SQLDBInteraction.DataContainer DC_Time = new SQLDBInteraction.DataContainer();

    SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList parmsTime = new SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList();
    Dictionary<SqlParameter, int> SqlCmdParDict = new Dictionary<SqlParameter, int>();
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.CommandText = AppDb.MetaSqlSProc.Time.Name;
    parmsTime.SP_Name = AppDb.MetaSqlSProc.Time.Name;
    parmsTime.TableName = AppDb.MetaSqlTable.Time.Name;

    //While folowing implementation Does Work I comented it out to try using the SP Struct
    //ParmsTTime.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SPTime.ParNameMonth, 9));
    //ParmsTTime.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SPTime.ParNameReasonid, 1));
    //ParmsTTime.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SPTime.ParNameYear, 2012));
    //ParmsTTime.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SPTime.ParNameUserid, 3571));


    //here's where I'm currently stuck, in section below. trying to assign values for the SqlCommand
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(SPTime.ParNameMonth, 9);
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(SPTime.ParNameYear, 2012);
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(SPTime.ParNameReasonid, 1);
    SPTime.Userid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    SPTime.Userid.SqlValue = 3571;
    return DC_Time.LocalTbl_V3(ParmsTime);
 }
```

**UPDATE**

The last lines of the code above is trying to implement the parameters assignment, thus it will no longer be required to use:

`SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList.SP_Params` (which is `List<SqlParameter>`).

And instead, I would really like to be able to use `SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList.SqlCmd.Parameters` as it is already used for most of the required steps to interact with the database.

This is how I will drop some unnecessary usage of extra variables while at the same time I wanted to assign SqlCmd (`parmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(......)`) with the struct - `SPTime` Real `SqlParameters` instead of using the strings that represents their name (e.g.  `parameter.name` - (`SPTime.ParNameMonth, someValue`)).

**Final stage- SQL transaction**

The `SQLDBInteraction` class that does the transaction:

```C#
public class SQLDBInteraction
{
    public class SqlParamList
    {
        public SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        public List<SqlParameter> SP_Params = new List<SqlParameter>();
        public String SP_Name;
        public string TableName;
        public string SelectCommand;
        ///public SqlCommandType SelectedCmdType;
    }

    public class DataContainer
    {
        public DataTable LocalTbl_V3(SqlParamList Params)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection;
            DataTable Usrs = new DataTable(Params.TableName);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter;

            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HTConn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (Params.SqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnection)
                {
                    using (sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Params.SqlCmd.CommandText, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        if (sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count > 0 == false)
                        {
                            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = Params.SqlCmd;
                            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(Usrs);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Usrs;
        }
```

I will really appreciate it if someone will find what am I doing wrong with the part of the stored procedure's parameters assigned to the SQL command.

Comment: Have you read about ORMs, e.g. Entity Framework? Is there a strong reason to use `DataTables` rather than typed entities? Is there a strong reason to use stored procedures? Your code is absolutely not thread-safe and has too much of unnecessary classes involved in the simplest operations like reading the data from DB.

Comment: @almaz say, do you want to see how exactly the SP LOOKS LIKE or Did You Really Know As To What exactly Does It Do In DB ? did you think it is something like : `select * From Table` **??**,  it has half a page or even almost a full page of code that makes a report of accouts

Comment: @LoneXcoder almaz doesn't know what your stored procedure looks like, which is why I think he was asking you questions, not really giving suggestions. And ORMs can work with stored procedures.

Comment: well, based on parameter names ('userid', 'month', 'year', 'eventid') and the SP name 'GetTimesWithCustomerNames' it does look like a simple select with a couple of tables at most ;).

OK, what about ORMs and usage of `DataTable`? Why do you need to do all the low-level work yourselves?

Comment: @svick i would like to keep it simple. this is WebForms , Not Mvc4 . The Website is `IIS6` `sql2005` `Winserver2003` AND `ASP` !! (CLASSIC) i am trying to do some touches ( and me also being still fresh Developer(just few month Self Learning) i'd like to implement it my self . any suggestions as to where to start ? a sample code . usage example for where would you start as it is to try atleast fine tuning the project ??

Comment: @almaz "why...low level , my self" , i am learning , i like low level some times if it does not smell like Sewerage while i try work on it (meaning too complex as if i will try `C` or `assembly` ) my brain will go dead that level, though , in `.net` with lots of sugar , i like to get as deep as i can , then and only then , as i am done, learn how `microsoft EF` or the company that is doing HiberSomthing ... works , i will be less dissoriented and i will be able to see through it , maybe , atleast see at all ...

Comment: @LoneXcoder Well, using ORM could actually make your code simpler, it means you don't have to deal with `SqlConnection`s ` and `SqlDataAdapter`s and `DataTable`s, you get a nice, strongly-typed collection of objects.

Comment: @LoneXcoder can you please avoid syntax errors in your questions? It goes a long way to improve the quality of the question, which will bring you more and better answers. (Example of a tool for it: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to do something like this

```
public interface DbProc
{
    public SqlCommand GetCommand();
}

public class MyProc : DbProc
{
    private SqlCommand _cmd;

    public const string COMMAND_TEXT = "spc_MyProc";
    public const string PARAM1 = "@Param1";
    public const string PARAM2 = "@Param2";        

    public MyProc(int param1, string param2)
    {
        _cmd = new SqlCommand(COMMAND_TEXT);
        _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(PARAM1, param1);
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(PARAM2, param2);
    }

    public SqlCommand GetCommand()
    {
        return _cmd;
    }
}

public class Db
{
    public DataTable ExecuteProc(DbProc proc)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = proc.GetCommand();
        ConfigureCommand(cmd);
        // execute the command into a data table
        return result;
    }

    // Set the common settings for all commands
    private void ConfigureCommand(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;            
    }
}
```

Comment: hi andy , thanks for your answer, I am in a little time-out so I can't really check on that solution , but I will review this further next week hopefully , in first glance it does look as a fine approach , thanks I will look in to it and try implement it instead of my answer , so it will be the right answer eventually if it works . thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you idea how your code would look like if you use Entity Framework:

```
using (var db = new HpDatabaseContext())
{
    return db.GetTimesWithCustomerNames(userId, month, year, reasonId).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: did you mention a 4 files scaterd around the folder xmls and some other UFO like extansions?, the key idea is to complete my code, then to compare it to `EF` (i am thinking of performance too i will check on this) ( by the way my implementaion logic is in these moments with this acutal question and goals to implemet querys as short as it could be you just need to initialize the struct : which table which sp you want to invoke.vwalla. just connect form fields to parameters in code behind=report is in page faster than ablink of an eye im ready to compare it to any new approach exists(speed wise)

Comment: You should not worry about performance since it is just a [premature optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). And quite likely it will work faster than populating a `DataTable` with `SqlDataAdapter`. It's good to understand how things work under the hood, but if you want to learn how to write good maintainable production code it's better to start using proven techniques. The sooner you start using them the faster you'll learn how to use them properly.

Answer (score -1):

this is aventually what i am using (atleast For now)

...as there will ,i guess.. always be, further developments.

i will mark this as the answer soon , though you are still very welcome to post comments, or better yet, your improved version .

anyways this is an example for how a stored procedure is stored in my "DbSchema" namespace

```
    public static class RobSelect_Update_tblTC_CPA_ByDDL_paramNames
    {
        static SqlParameter aDepartment, bUid, cMonth, dYear, eUpdateFirst;

        public static List<SqlParameter> SqlParlstCPA(string SelectedDepartmentID, string SelectedUserID, string SelectedMonth, string selectedYear, string AbitValuIfUpdateFirst)
        {
            aDepartment = new SqlParameter( a_UsrDepartment, SelectedDepartmentID);
            bUid = new SqlParameter(b_UsrID, SelectedUserID);
            cMonth = new SqlParameter(c_Month, SelectedMonth);
            dYear = new SqlParameter(d_Year, selectedYear);
            eUpdateFirst = new SqlParameter(e_Updateit_bit, AbitValuIfUpdateFirst);


            List<SqlParameter> RetSqlParLst  = new List<SqlParameter>();
            RetSqlParLst.Add(aDepartment);
            RetSqlParLst.Add(bUid);
            RetSqlParLst.Add(cMonth);
            RetSqlParLst.Add(dYear);
            RetSqlParLst.Add(eUpdateFirst);

            return RetSqlParLst;
        }
        static readonly string a_UsrDepartment = "@Department",
                     b_UsrID = "@Uid",
                     c_Month = "@month",
                     d_Year = "@year",
                     e_Updateit_bit = "@updateItFirst";
    }
```

Comment: downvoters i dont count in those votes without a comment of why ,as it is being offensive approach Comments may help to explain what you think about it instead